# How to configure multiple database and using failover in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I've used Codeigniter3.0.4 as the document provide I can't configure multiple database and using **'failover' => array()**.

I found an errros **You have not selected a database type to connect to.** on my website if I used this options

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['failover'] = array(
    array(
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'com',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => TRUE,
        'db_debug' => TRUE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE
    ),
    array(
        'hostname' => 'localhost2',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'ABC',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => TRUE,
        'db_debug' => TRUE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE
    )
);
```

Please help how should I do.

Comment: you have to set the default/group configuration of database. If default/group configuration fails then only it'll check the failover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the default/group configuration of database. If default/group configuration fails then only it'll check the failover

```
$db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'database_name',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => TRUE,
        'db_debug' => TRUE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(
            array(
                    'hostname' => 'localhost1',
                    'username' => '',
                    'password' => '',
                    'database' => '',
                    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
                    'dbprefix' => '',
                    'pconnect' => TRUE,
                    'db_debug' => TRUE,
                    'cache_on' => FALSE,
                    'cachedir' => '',
                    'char_set' => 'utf8',
                    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
                    'swap_pre' => '',
                    'encrypt' => FALSE,
                    'compress' => FALSE,
                    'stricton' => FALSE
            ),
            array(
                    'hostname' => 'localhost2',
                    'username' => '',
                    'password' => '',
                    'database' => '',
                    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
                    'dbprefix' => '',
                    'pconnect' => TRUE,
                    'db_debug' => TRUE,
                    'cache_on' => FALSE,
                    'cachedir' => '',
                    'char_set' => 'utf8',
                    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
                    'swap_pre' => '',
                    'encrypt' => FALSE,
                    'compress' => FALSE,
                    'stricton' => FALSE
            )
        )
);
```

Comment: I got errors 
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Exception

Message: Configured database connection is persistent. Aborting.

Filename: D:\Projects\wamp\www\com\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_database_driver.php

Line Number: 94

Comment: here pconnect is marked as persistent true so disable and see  `'pconnect' => FALSE,`